# angular-google-analytics with phonegap issue, "Refused to load the script"

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, google-analytics, meta-tags

i have issues with google analytics, i am using this angular plugin [angular-google-analytics](https://github.com/revolunet/angular-google-analytics).
and i see this error:

`Refused to load the script 'http://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'". Note that 'script-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback`

i noticed that when i remove this phonegap meta TAG from my header, i an NOT getting this error

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">
```

i don't know what this meta TAG is for or how is important. ?

any way after the error is gone, i don't see anything in the realtime view

```
gameApp.controller('MainController', function($scope, $location, Analytics) {
$scope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function(next, current) { 
    Analytics.trackPage($location.path());
 });
});
```

can you help me solve this issues.
thank you

Comment: I'm unable to get angular-google-analytics to work either.

Answer (score 0):

This tag is important to prevent XSS or malicious 'foreign' scripts.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">
```

Have you tried inserting the following into the above content attribute:

```
script-src 'self' https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval';
```

by whitelisting it specifically you should be able to load it.

In my angular apps I use the following code:

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function(){
  $window.ga('send', 'pageview', $location.$$path);
});
```

---

read

https://content-security-policy.com

https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/CR-CSP-20121115/#introduction